# Android Development: App crashes As soon as cuursor is called to search for a row in my table

Tags: mysql, sqlite, android-studio

I am quite new to android development, I am making an app in which i need to search a row in my table which has 3 columns Id, Items and User.

In this table I have to search for a particular user and return string `Items` of that row.

But as soon as I call cursor, the app crashes; why is that? And is there any other way to do this?

```
public String loadData(String user,Context context)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sq = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] Columns = {C1,C2,C3};

    Cursor cr = sq.query(Table2, Columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cr.getCount()==0) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Something Is wrong,Not Able to Load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "";
    }
    else {
        String ans = "";
        do {
            if (cr.getString(2).equals(user)) {
                ans = cr.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        } while(cr.moveToNext());

        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you used Room instead SQLlite

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650077/sqlite-database-vs-room-persistence-library

even Google suggest user to use Room too
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite?hl=id

You can see it in Caution box

Comment: Thank u very much for your advice , I will definitely try to use Room , but I just want to know , what is wrong here in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the cursor to a valid row before attempting to read column value with `getString()` from it. You can move it with e.g. `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()` that return `true` when the cursor is pointing to a valid row.

In other words, you need a `if (cr.moveToFirst())` before your do-while loop.